# Does distribution work with operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

For Example:

Let $V$ be a vector space.
$T: V \rightarrow  V$, $S_1: V \rightarrow V$, $S_2: V \rightarrow V$ are all operators.

sign: * (=composition)

does $T^*(S_1+S_2) = T^*S_1 + T^*S_2$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If all the operators are linear, then yes !

$(T^{*}(S_1+S_2))(v)=T(S_1v+S_2v)=T(S_1v)+T(S_2v)=(T^{*}S_1)(v)+(T^{*}S_2)(v)$.